# Does roxygen2 use a "prefix is known" heuristic?

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

**Hypothesis**

Roxygen2 uses a heuristic. If the prefix preceding the period is known (`merge`, `cut`), the method is an S3 method, otherwise (`slice`), it is an ordinary method.

**Question**

Is this heuristic documented? More importantly, is there a way to avert it? I should be able to write any unused identifier for a function name, without watching out for prefixes, which would also mean that there would be no future guarantees that one can offer regarding the stability of a given package. I understand that "S3 classes have no formal definition" (last vignette cited below), but it seems absurd to mess with what does have a formal definition. Plus, any future edits of a package to use a new package can suddenly make it necessary to invalidate an existing API.

I tried to fix this by editing the `NAMESPACE` file by hand after it is generated, but this sometimes messes up with package installation (in a way I don't yet understand). The following experiment is the setup for the question.

**Experiment**

After running `devtools::create("MyPackage")`, put the following code

```
#' @export
merge.apples <- function() {}

#' @export
merge.oranges <- function() {}

#' @export
cut.apples <- function() {}

#' @export
cut.oranges <- function() {}

#' @export
slice.apples <- function() {}

#' @export
slice.oranges <- function() {}
```

in `MyPackage/R/somefile.R`.

Now run `devtools::document()` (twice). You will see that the contents

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(cut,apples)
S3method(cut,oranges)
S3method(merge,apples)
S3method(merge,oranges)
export(slice.apples)
export(slice.oranges)
```

have been generated in the file `MyPackage/NAMESPACE`. In other words, four functions have been assumed to be S3 functions.

From the pages

```
vignette("namespace", package = "roxygen2") 
vignette("roxygen2", package = "roxygen2") 
vignette("rd", package = "roxygen2")
```

it is now (since circa 2014?) sufficient to write `#' @export` before either an S3 method or an ordinary method, and `roxygen2` will figure out which it is.